# VBA Rounding With Cell Values

Tags: vba, rounding

I'm trying to round every populate cell in column AD:AD to 4 decimals and ends when the next cell is blank.

I thought something like this would work but it errors out on the cell.value.

```
Sub Round_4()
For Each cell In [AD:AD]
    If cell = "" Then Exit Sub
    cell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Round(cell.Value, 4)
Next cell
```

End Sub

Any suggestions?

Comment: Its working for me... What is the error you are getting...  Try renaming the variable "cell" to something else... "Cell" might be a keyword

Answer (score 1):

You could work only down to the first empty cell with

```
Range("AD1", Range("AD1").End(xlDown)).Value = Evaluate("round(" & Range("AD1", Range("AD1").End(xlDown)).Address & ",4)")
```

Note this is using Activesheet reference. You can wrap in a With statement giving the parent sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
Dim myCell As Range
Dim myRange As Range

Set myRange = Excel.Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(worksheetNameGoesHereInDoubleQuotes).Range("AD:AD")

For Each myCell In myRange
    If Not IsEmpty(myCell) Then
        myCell.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Round(CDbl(myCell.Value), 4)
    'me being lazy with my range assignment
    ElseIf IsEmpty(myCell) Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Won't work if `myCell` contains text. Also, `IsEmpty(myCell)` - missing `Not`?

Comment: @BigBen because OP hasn't declared otherwise, I'm assuming all cells are numbers

Comment: But OP also hasn't declared that they _are_ all numbers.

Comment: (I'm trying to round every populate cell in column AD:AD to 4 decimals and ends when the next cell is blank.)

Plenty of info to assume they're all numbers.

Comment: If they're all numbers then why does `cell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Round(cell.Value, 4)` throw an error? My point is that it's safer to be defensive. A "populated" cell is not equivalent to a "numeric" cell.

Comment: @BigBen so then cast it to a double. my assumption is entirely valid given the context